# How is delta-import listening to DB and updates?

Tags: solr

I am new to *solr search* and *DIH*. I did some research but not quite figure out. So how is *delta-import* updates the solr index, i mean is it automatic listening all database all the time or frequently checking in 5 min(?) or do we manualy activate the *delta-import* check if anything updated or added new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing about "delta-import" is that it assumes that most of the content has already been indexed, so there are specific queries being run to determine what has changed since the last time the import ran, and to detect which documents has been removed from the database. You have to write queries (and have a data structure behind the scenes that support these queries) to let Solr determine these things for you.

There is no listening for changes, and there is no automagic import running every five minutes (or another interval). You trigger a delta-import the same way as you'd trigger a full import:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dih/dataimport?command=delta-import
```

But instad of running the regular queries, [the `delta` versions of the queries run  instead](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#configuring-the-dih-configuration-file).

```
<entity name="feature"
          query="select DESCRIPTION from FEATURE where ITEM_ID='${item.ID}'"
          deltaQuery="select ITEM_ID from FEATURE where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
          parentDeltaQuery="select ID from item where ID=${feature.ITEM_ID}"> 
    <field name="features" column="DESCRIPTION" />
</entity>
```

If you're building an application today, I *strongly* recommend submitting the documents directly to Solr when they change in your application instead of using the Data Import Handler, as that will scale better, give you faster updates and give you complete control over the update process.

Comment: Thanks it really helps.